# Trigger logging from within Wix script

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.5

Normally, to enable logging, you'd say `msiexec ... /l*v [or any other combination]`.
You can also enable logging ***all*** products via the [registry tweak](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/223300).

Note that these are all *outside* actions, in a sense that the `wxs` script is not the one specifying the logging options.

Is there a way to control logging from within the `wxs` script? Preferably to a folder like `INSTALLDIR\Logs`?

Is this a good practice? I know uninstalling will leave the `Log` folder behind, unless I clean it up somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can request a log verbosity level with the [MsiLogging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370322%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property. However, you can't control where the log is created and both level and location are overridden by anything the user specifies.

Comment: This seems promising. The article mentions [MsiLogFileLocation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370321(v=vs.85).aspx) which can be used to specify the default path. Doesn't that work? I understand if the user overrides, then so be it but otherwise, this would suffice to enable default logging, right?

Comment: Nope. MsiLogFileLocation "is set" -- by MSI. (It's a bad doc topic, as it doesn't specify. Most other topics in the MSI SDK use "the installer sets the value" to indicate read-only properties.)

Comment: Is it possible to specify the logging via a bootstrapper exe (that launches msi with the log options)?

Comment: Yes and bootstrappers can use API functions like MsiEnableLog.